# How to compute the Jacobian of a function with an Hadamard division?

Tags: matrix-calculus

I have a function

$$
f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n \\
f(x) = A^{-1}(b \ \oslash \ x)
$$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $b, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and I cannot figure out how to compute the Jacobian of $f$ by using Matrix calculus

Comment: What is the meaning of $\oslash$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Questions which provide context tend to attract higher quality answers. Please see: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net with $\oslash$ I mean Hadamard or element-wise division of the two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\d{{\rm diag}}
\def\D{{\rm Diag}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$There
is a well known trick for replacing the Hadamard product of vector by the regular matrix product with a diagonal matrix generated by the vector, and for recovering the vector from the diagonal matrix by multiplying by the *all-ones* vector.
$$\eqalign{
B &= \D(b) \\
Bc &= b\odot c \\
b &= B\o \\
}$$
This trick can be extended to Hadamard division by using the matrix inverse (assuming that the vector does not have any components equal to zero).
$$\eqalign{
c\oslash b 
\;=\; B^{-1}c
\;=\; \left(B^{-1}C\right)\o
}$$
Applying this trick to the current problem yields
$$\eqalign{
f &= A^{-1}(b\oslash x) \\&= A^{-1}BX^{-1}\o \\
df &= A^{-1}B\,\c{dX^{-1}}\o \\
&= A^{-1}B\c{\left(-X^{-1}\,dX\,X^{-1}\right)}\o \\
&= -A^{-1}BX^{-2}\,dx \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}
&= -A^{-1}BX^{-2} \\
}$$
where the part in red is a well-known result from matrix calculus. Also the fact that diagonal matrices like $(B,X)$ commute with one another has been utilized in several steps.

Answer (score 0):

So let's break this down, you have $f=g\circ h$ where

\begin{align}
&g:{\bf R}^n\rightarrow{\bf R}^n\;\;\;g(x) = A^{-1}x\\
&h:{\bf R}^n\rightarrow{\bf R}^n\;\;\;h(x) = b\oslash x
\end{align}

By the chain rule, $f' = (g'\circ h)\cdot h'$, where $g'$ and $h'$ are both $n\times n$ matrices, and where $f'$ will also be an $n\times n$ matrix.

Since $g'$ is a constant, this reduces to $f'=g' \cdot h'$, where $h'$ will be a diagonal matrix since $\oslash$ acts coordinate-wise on $x$, can you take it from here?